# std::initializer_list with std::thread

Tags: c++, c++17, initializer-list

```
myNameSpace::functionName(this, {"abc", "abc1"});  // working fine
```

working fine, but

```
std::thread(myNameSpace::functionName<ClassName>(this, {"abc", "abc1"})); 
                     //error: invalid use of void expression.
```

Please suggest me what I am missing here. or how to do it.

```
namespace myNameSpace {
    template<typename T>
    void functionName(T* cm, std::initializer_list<std::string_view> args) { ... }
}
```

Comment: @George We have a whole section devoted for answers complete with peer review and acceptance features - please use it! Hover your mouse over the "add a comment" link to see what comments are not for; also consider taking the [Tour] again to refresh your knowledge on how the SO model works. Thanks!

Comment: You should not pass initializer lists across thread boundaries like this. Use a proper container type.

Comment: Please don't correct relevant errors in your question. There are already answers explaining the error that you fixed and your edit would invalidate these. I have reverted your edit.

Comment: You should present your code in the form of an [mcve], like [this](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0d6bf7add9eb65c). Save us from having to do that for you just to see the problem.

Comment: @Asteroids With Wings My comment was just to highlight the incorrect syntax ( ironically mine was also incorrect ), and the issue with creating a temporary thread. I didn't explain anything so it just didn't feel worth posting as an answer ( I've removed it anyway for the aforementioned error ) :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, that is not how you start a thread. You are calling it, and passing the result as an argument to start the thread. But, `void` is not a valid argument for starting a thread, nor is it indeed any sort of useful expression in any sense.

You'd be writing something like this instead:

```
std::thread(&myNameSpace::functionName<ClassName>, this, {"abc", "abc1"});
```

Your next problem is that there is no facility in the language for the compiler to deduce what you mean by `{"abc", "abc1"}` there. With a direct function call to `functionName`, it can work it out, because the function call machinery knows what the candidate overloads are, but that is just not the case with this "broken down" construction.

[It's possible to fix that](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df964d53c56864c4) by specifying the type:

```
std::thread(&myNameSpace::functionName<ClassName>, this, std::initializer_list<std::string_view>{"abc", "abc1"});
```

However, I recommend you just pass (and accept) a `std::vector<std::string_view>` instead. It'll be much easier and much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

`std::thread` receives a callable as first parameter, you sent it `void` (The invoke result of `myNameSpace::functionName`).

What you need to do is

```cpp
std::thread(myNameSpace::functionName<ClassName>, this, std::initializer_list<std::string_view>({"abc", "abc1"})));
```

Note that explicit casting to `std::initializer_list` is required, as `std::initializer_list` is non deductible type.

Answer (score 1):

For threads you need to provide function reference and arguments parameters in arguments list like following:

```
template< class Function, class... Args >
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

in your case you have to provide the arguments as following:

```
std::thread(myNameSpace::functionName<ClassName>,this, std::initializer_list<std::string_view>({"abc", "abc1"}));
```